# Re-entry vs Re-buy in multi table tournaments

Tags: poker-strategy

Why do both players and operators prefer Re-entry to Re-buy in guaranteed multi table tournaments?

Answer (score 1):

Well for the players that answer will be extremely opinion based, plus I don't think most players really mind or care once they get to play. Let me explain the difference between the two re-buy and re-entry.

Re-buy

1. Not always true but often you remain at the same seat when you re-buy.
2. You often don't pay rake again.
3. These games tend to play looser before the re-buys end of re-buys and tighter after.
4. If you decide to not re-buy straight away you're gone from the tournament.

Re-entry

1. When re-entering you will be moved seat and table, if possible. If it's a big tournament and there is a waiting list you will be put to the end of the list if you want to re-enter.
2. You will pay rake again.
3. Games, often, don't play looser normally before re-entries end.
4. You can walk away and come back and re-enter whenever you want, as long as re-entries are still available.

For Operators/Casinos they like them because they get to charge rake again, re-buy tournaments mostly don't recharge rake. I have worked for operators who do charge rake again for re-buys but most don't, I think it's kind of bad form personally. They can also count each re-enter as a new player so it makes their numbers look much better.

For players they can cool off and walk away if they take a bad beat and bust in re-enter. In re-buy they need to re-buy straight away.

This is very opinion based to answer for players, but for the casino or tournament operator it's pretty easy to see why they prefer re-entry, more money for them and better looking numbers.